# How to draw circle at random position in between of two circles?

Tags: javascript, html, math, canvas, kineticjs

I have two circles. one is with 150 radius and other one is 350 radius. I want to place number of circles in between space of 150 - 350 radius. It shouldn't be over-placed(overwrite) on other circle which is already placed. It should be placed randomly on every refresh. Can some one please give me idea/logic of how to do this in canvas. Javascript.

[image: Sample Image red question mark circle I wanted to place]

**[EDIT]**

1. Radius of all circles are predefined.

Comment: A) Is the number of circles you want 1) fixed 2) random with a minimum and max value (ex: between 5 and 8 circles) 3) completely random (1 to the maximum possible) ? B) I guess that for the radius of the circles,, randomness is within a range (ex : between 20 and 50 radius) is that it ?

Comment: A) 3) Completely random with maximum possible circles to be placed. B)  Yes it is with in the range of say 20 - 50.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/aGq8p/

[image]

The trick here is to create random circles but also to be sure they don't overlap previously created circles.

Here's annotated code:

```
function randomCircle(){

    // define random radius

    var radius=minCircle+Math.random()*(maxCircle-minCircle);

    // define random distance between inner/outer rings

    var distFromCenter=innerRadius+radius+Math.random()*(outerRadius-innerRadius-radius*2);

    // define random angle

    var angle=Math.random()*PI2;

    // calculate the x,y of the defined circle

    var x=cx+distFromCenter*Math.cos(angle);
    var y=cy+distFromCenter*Math.sin(angle);

    // check this new circle versus all previous random circles for a collision 

    var hit=false;
    for(var i=0;i<randomCircles.length;i++){
        var circle=randomCircles[i];
        var dx=circle.cx-x;
        var dy=circle.cy-y;
        var r=circle.radius+radius;
        if(dx*dx+dy*dy<=r*r){
            hit=true;
        }
    }

    // if no collision occurred, add this new circle to the existing circles array

    if(!hit){
        var color=randomColor();
        randomCircles.push({cx:x,cy:y,radius:radius,color:color}); 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As for *drawing* the actual images, that's up to you, but here's how you place the circles:

First, pick a Θ, at random, between 0° and 360°.

Then pick a radius `r1` for your little circle, between 0 and 50 (half of the 100-pixel width of the "track").

Then pick a center location `r2`, between 150 + `r1` and 350 - `r1`.

Now draw a circle radius `r1` at the location given in [polar coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinates) by (Θ, `r2`).

Comment: I am investigating this. Will update you If any thing is required. Polar coordinates needs to look on.

Comment: Can you please explain me here How to apply polar coordinates? Can you please give me some pseudo code of that. Thanks,